# How to express $\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+j}\right)$ in rectangular form?

Tags: complex-numbers

Trying to understand how to express this complex number $\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+j}\right)$ into rectangular form.

I thought to use $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and  $ y = r\sin(\theta)$, but I am pretty sure that is wrong.

Comment: There was absolutely no reason to edit the question, it is my preference to decide if I want parenthesis around theta. So irrelevant and trivial to edit the question.

Comment: Can you calculate the magnitude and the argument of $1/(1+j)$ (that is, can you express $1/(1+j)$ in polar form)? If so, do you know how to compute the complex logarithm of a number in that form?

Comment: @GenoC The edited version corrected typesetting.

Comment: @GregMartin, I am so stupid, I am sorry I see what you mean now.

Comment: You're not stupid—you're simply learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by $\ln$, you mean the main branch of the complex logarithm (remember, the complex logarithm is a [fairly complicated topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)), then use the fact that $$\log z = \log|z| + i\cdot \mathrm{Arg}(z).$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln\frac1{1+i}=-\ln(1+i)=-\ln\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}=-(\ln\sqrt2+i\pi/4)=\ln\frac1{\sqrt2}-i\pi/4$$
with the usual caveat about $\ln$'s multivaluedness.

Comment: Eh, thank you for the answer but I want to make sure I know how to do this for future questions for my Linear systems class. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @GenoC What I did is essentially what Greg Martin outlined in the comment on the main question.

Comment: I am confused where $\frac{\pi}{4}$ comes from?

Comment: @GenoC It is the _argument_ of $1+i$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+i}\Bigr)=-\ln\Bigl(1+i\Bigr)= -\ln\Bigl(\sqrt{2}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr)\Bigr)$$

$$-\ln\Bigl(\sqrt{2}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr)\Bigr)=-\ln\Bigl(\sqrt{2}\Bigl(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+{i}\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)\Bigr)$$
$r(\cos\theta +i\sin\theta)$ can be written as $re^{i\theta}$

$$-\ln\Bigl(\sqrt{2}\Bigl(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+{i}\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)\Bigr)=-\ln\Bigl(\sqrt{2}\Bigl(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigr)\Bigr)=-\ln\sqrt{2} -\ln{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}$$

$$= \ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} -i\frac{\pi}{4}$$